# Lost data upon migration from standalone server to one node replica set

Tags: mongodb

I was attempting to migrate my standalone mongo server to a single node replica set using the following instructions: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

Upon restarting the docker container with the -replSet argument and initiating within the mongo shell, I noticed that the replica set was created, but virtually all of my database collections disappeared. The /data/db folder argument hasn't changed and I haven't assigned a different config file. Is there any hope in recovering my data?

Comment: Did you update your config file to convert to a replica set? Do your data files present in the /data/db folder?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: same thing happened with me. Is this normal during this process or did we miss something?